# Como pegar o resultado de um procedure que está no servidor datasnap

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, delphi-xe3, delphi-xe5, datasnap

precisando de uma ajuda aqui 
la no servidor datasnap tenho essa função

//query que esta no fqy_SaldoRs é "PRC_SALDO_MOTOQUEIRO :pMoto" Que nada mais é do que uma query que recebe um paramentro do tipo inteiro e retorna um double

```
function TServerMethods1.fnc_RetornaSaldo(matricula: Integer): Boolean;
begin
 Result := False;
  with fqy_SaldoRs do
  begin
    Close;
    Params[0].AsInteger := matricula;
    Open;
    Result := True;
  end;
  fqy_SaldoRs.Close;
end;
```

O servidor e datasnap webbroker 
como eu faço para pegar esse retorno do lado cliente ???

Comment: Acho que é só modificar a função `fnc_RetornaSaldo` trocando o retorno de `Boolean` para `Double` e no `Result` coloque o valor retornado pela Query.

Comment: Acho que isso não muda pelo menos no meu entender se o select retornar algo é porque ele é true assim como se retornasse 1 seria um integer eu poderia perfeitamente ter declarado essa function como integer. A questão é la no cliente como faço para pegar o resultado ?

Comment: Cara, esse teu código tá meio zuado. Nessa estrutura o `Result` vai ser sempre `True`, a não ser que dê algum erro antes do `Result := True;` . Nesse seu caso, acho que poderia trocar o `True` por `not(IsEmpty)`.
Outra questão é o nome do seu método, aparentemente pelo nome eu espero que ele me retorne o Saldo, e ele só vai me dizer se eu tenho dados na tabela saldo para uma determinada matricula.
Agora vamos de fato a sua pergunta. Você chega a receber alguma coisa no Client? Como está sendo feita a chamada desse método? Tem outros métodos no seu servidor que está funcionando?

Comment: Você já atualizou as funções do servidor no cliente?...